# Pandas comparing two rows in a database

Tags: python, pandas, compare, row

I have a dataframe like this;

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['apple', 'golden', 3], ['apple', 'green', 6], ['banana', 'golden', 9], ['apple', 'golden', 5], ['apple', 'green', 6], ['banana', 'golden', 6]]),
                   columns=['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3'])
df

    Column1 Column2 Column3
0   apple   golden  3
1   apple   green   6
2   banana  golden  9
3   apple   golden  5
4   apple   green   6
5   banana  golden  6
```

I want to compare "Column1" rows with iterating in a new Column4. If there is a difference I want to write down True, if not False.

```
    Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
0   apple   golden  3       False
1   apple   green   6       False
2   banana  golden  9       True
3   apple   golden  5       True
4   apple   green   6       False
5   banana  golden  6       True
```

And lastly, if comparing result is true, I want to add Column1 item to a list.

```
list = ['banana']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare shifted values for not equal with replace first value to original `Column1` by `fillna`:

```
df['Column4'] = df.Column1.shift().fillna(df.Column1).ne(df.Column1)

print (df)
  Column1 Column2  Column3  Column4
0   apple  golden        3    False
1   apple   green        6    False
2  banana  golden        9     True
3   apple  golden        5     True
4   apple   green        6    False
5  banana  golden        6     True
```

For list dont use `list`, because python code word:

```
L = df.loc[df['Column4'], 'Column1'].unique().tolist()
print (L)
['banana', 'apple']
```

Comment: I don't have a constant value like banana. Values are changing like: banana, apple, pineapple. Should I use for loop?

Comment: @CanerUçal - Best in pandas dont use loops, if performance is important. Added vectorized solution to answer.

Comment: When I use .shift() method, last row comparison is gone.

Comment: @CanerUçal - in my solution is gone first value - it is replaced by original value by `.fillna(df.Column1)`, so if compare for not equal by `ne` is first value always `False`

Comment: Sorry I'm new at python. I understand clearly now. It works. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have new challange now. Firstly I need to check "Column2". If there is a change in Column2, Column4 value must be false. Is it possible without for loop?

Comment: @piseynir - Is possible post new question? And describe what is difference with this question above?

Comment: OK i will post today. Same with this question, only difference there is a "if condition" with Column2.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, this should work:

```
df['Column4'] = np.where(df.Column1.shift(1) != df.Column1, True, False)
df['Column4'][0] = False  #Since the above method would set the first row as True comparing it to nothing


list = df['Column1'].loc[df.Column4].to_list()
```

The above line would give a list of values in `Column1` when value in `Column4` is `True`.